# Why is the immediate value of SVC not used in the arm64 ABI?

Tags: performance, optimization, arm, arm64, abi

In aarch32, more precisely the ARM-OABI, the immediate value of `swi` was still used to transfer the syscall number. In ARM-EABI, on the other hand, a register is used instead. `swi #0` then indicates that a register should be used.

This option is no longer available in aarch64, so I use this combination all the time:

```
mov  x8, syscall_number
svc  #0
```

**Why do I have to add an additional 4 bytes of code size here and the immediate value remains unused this time?**

According to the ARM Programmer's Guide, the immediate value is stored in the *Exception Syndrome Register* `ESR_EL` and should therefore be readable with `mrs`. Or is that already a too big loss of performance?

---

References:

- [Stackoverflow: Implementation of syscall() on ARM-OABI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48183434/implementation-of-syscall-on-arm-oabi-what-is-svc-0x900071)
- [Stackoverflow: How to implement system call in ARM64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431095/how-to-implement-system-call-in-arm64)
- [ARM Cortex-A Series Programmer's Guide for ARMv8-A: The Exception Syndrome Register](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/den0024/a/aarch64-exception-handling/synchronous-and-asynchronous-exceptions/the-exception-syndrome-register)

Comment: perhaps because it didnt make sense in aarch32.  or perhaps because it is easier to set a register than hardcode the instruction immediate. (have a single helper function than many helper functions)

Comment: It can't have anything to do with `ESR_ELx` - that register needs to be read anyway just to tell apart syscalls from other synchronous exceptions like data aborts.

Comment: It depends on the OS's choices, really. ARM64 Windows uses the immediate value on the SVC instruction to select which system call. I would argue that putting the system call number as an immediate is slightly better for security, because it limits ROP gadget opportunities.